Django model has ManyToMany field, how to get all IDs without fetching the objects?
I have a data structure like this:
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, related_name="pizzas")

class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

And to get all topping IDs related to a pizza I can do this:
list(map(lambda t: t.id, pizza.toppings.all()))

But this fetches all toppings completely from the database, even thought I only need the IDs. Is there a way to get the IDs without fetching the complete objects (for performance reasons)?

Use .values_list() methods to get only the IDs as tuples:
topping_ids = pizza.toppings.all().values_list("id")
# Example of result ( (4), (5), (12), (54) )


To make it a list of numbers instead of tuples I've added flat=True, this might work!

You can work with a Prefetch object [Django-doc] that limits the columns fetched with .only(…) [Django-doc]:
from django.db.models import Prefetch

Pizza.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('toppings', Topping.objects.only('id')))
But very likely the reason you got performance issues in the first place was the so-called N+1 problem where you first fetch the records for Pizza, and then per record, you make an extra query for the Topping objects.

I had this problem indeed, and when fixing it I was looking for another quick win. Maybe the problem is not big enough to add this "complexity" now, I was hoping for a solution like pizza.toppings_id that improved readability and performance.

@Lodewijck: .toppings_id will improve readability, but making a query per Pizza which will thus result in a lot of roundtrips to the database. You can also add a to_attr=... to the Prefetch, like Prefetch('toppings', Topping.objects.only('id'), to_attr='topping_ids') so that you can still use the .toppings as "full" topping objects, and .topping_ids for Toppings that only encapsulate the id.
